# Why the jQuery's ajax ".always" functions is not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, long-polling

I have following Javascript code which always ask server for some data.

```
;var EVENTS = {};
;(function($) {

    EVENTS.Test = {
      getEventsData: function() {

        var events_request = $.ajax({
            url: "test1.php",
            contentType: 'application/json-rpc',
            type: "GET",
            timeout: 30000
        });

        events_request.done(function(results) {alert(results);});

        events_request.fail(function(results) {alert(results);});

        events_request.always(this.getEventsData);
    }   
    };

})(jQuery);

EVENTS.Test.getEventsData();
```

Server side php is as following

```
<?php
sleep(5); 
echo "This is response";
?>
```

What I want to do is get the data from server in case either ".done or .fail" finish, so I use ".always" function. But only two request is made to the server, after that no request is made.
I used Firebug to debug.But unfortunately no any error. How can I know why the ajax is not working after two request. How to make it working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is when the `getEventsData` method is invoked by ajax callback `this` does not refer to the `Test` object so `this.getEventsData` will be undefined. The solution is to use [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) to pass a custom execution context to the callback

```
events_request.always($.proxy(this.getEventsData, this));
```

Another option is to set the context option of [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) so that all the callbacks will get a custom execution context.

> This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By
>   default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings
>   used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged with the settings passed to
>   $.ajax).

Comment: Or just `$.proxy(this.getEventsData, this)`, assuming the function is called with the correct context the first time.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens yes... otherwise even the `this.getEventsData` reference wouldn't work...

Comment: Thats this what is needed. BTW, I prefer $.proxy()